# android keep the aspect ratio of camera in both the modes

Tags: android, camera, aspect-ratio

I need to maintain the aspect ratio of the camera preview in both the modes(portrait and landscape) without stretching or skewing.
I have done some searches on this problem but couldnt find any solution . Can anyone provide the right solution for it.

thanks in advance.

Comment: you should find height and width of screen, find the aspect ratio and assign it to the camera's layout, all that programmatically.

Comment: ok is that all needed?

Comment: can't be sure if thats 100% your answer..but try to do it that way..search how to find width/height programmatically, how to find the aspect ratio from those, and how to set your camera's layout width and height programmatically..

Comment: @aparnap If I am understanding your problem correctly, you want to show your camera image preview in an imageview by maintaining the aspect ratio, if yes I would say just use android:scaleType="center" in your xml where you are showing your preview. Android will take care of rest.

Comment: @dex No,the preview should not be stretched or skewed when we rotate the device.

Comment: and you are showing the preview in an image view right ??

Comment: @Tony i find this link https://coderanch.com/t/574244/Android/Mobile/customize-cameras-height-width-programmatically usable but the image is skewed when it is in portrait.

Comment: @dex yes in an image view :)

Comment: then you can use imageview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.Center)

Comment: @dex but i need to show the camera preview in surfaceview  perfectly , without squeezing or stretching.